# Cannot run bcrpyt or werkzeug in my python 3 environment

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt, werkzeug

I am doing a course in flask and python 3.  I have set up a python 3.6 environment with the following libraries in a requirement.txt file:

```
alembic==0.9.9
blinker==1.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Dance==0.14.0
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-OAuth==0.12
Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.4
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
lazy==1.3
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauthlib==2.0.7
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-editor==1.0.3
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.6
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.2
urllib3==1.22
URLObject==2.4.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wincertstore==0.2
WTForms==2.1
```

And I am trying to run this scripts in the environment:

```
#pip install flask-bcrypt
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

# Create the Hasher
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

hashed_pass = bcrypt.generate_password_hash('mypassword')
print(hashed_pass)
wrong_check = bcrypt.check_password_hash(hashed_pass, 'wrongpass')
print(wrong_check)
right_check = bcrypt.check_password_hash(hashed_pass, 'mypassword')
print(right_check)
```

but I get this error:

```
(myflaskenv2) C:\Users\dthomas\Documents\python_projects\Python and Flask Bootcamp\authentication>bcrypt-attempt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dthomas\Documents\python_projects\Python and Flask Bootcamp\authentication\bcrypt-attempt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bcrypt'
```

Likewise when I try a werkzeug script:

```
# pip install Werkzeug
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash

# Can add options to this like salt and method
# For example: method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=8 (these are defaults)
hashed_pass = generate_password_hash('mypassword')
print(hashed_pass)
wrong_check = check_password_hash(hashed_pass,'wrong')
print(wrong_check)
right_check = check_password_hash(hashed_pass,'mypassword')
print(right_check)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dthomas\Documents\python_projects\Python and Flask Bootcamp\authentication\werkzeug-attempt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug'
```

I have tried:

- recreating a new environment
- uninstalling, installing different
- versions of werkzeug in pip2 and pip3, both inside and outside the
  environment
- tried it on different computers

Does anyone have an idea of the issue?

Comment: I don't see flask-bcrypt in requirements.txt. You can do pip show flask_bcrypt to see if it is installed. You should update the version of your modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is embarrassing.

I was typing `attempt-werkzeug.py` instead of `python attempt-werkzeug.py`

Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to upgrade Werkzeug, mine is Werkzeug==2.0.0 and Flask==2.0.0. It seems to be a version issue. try:

```
pip install --upgrade werkzeug
```

Also, you don't seem to have flask_bcrypt in your requirements.txt, you can see installation details [here](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Bcrypt/).

```
pip install Flask-Bcrypt
```

Now, try again.
You might also want to upgrade Flask too:

```
pip install --upgrade Flask
```